# How to send data from datalist in Angular to Rest api

Tags: html, angular

I have a frontend project in Angular where I have a Html file with a datalist and another backend project Restful API
How do I get the selected option from the datalist in Angular and send the value to my rest server. I use Glassfish. I want to read it in JSON format. 
Here is some code I already have and tried to use.

```
export class OrganizeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  restaurant = {
    naam: '',
    adres: ''
  };
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onOrganize(form: NgForm) {
    this.restaurant.naam = this.form.value.naam;
    this.restaurant.adres = this.form.value.adres;


    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/testproject/resources/restaurant', {
      naam: this.restaurant.naam,
      adres: this.restaurant.adres})
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
  }
  btnClick1= function () {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu');
  };
```

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form
      (ngSubmit)="onOrganize(f)"
      #f="ngForm">
      <label for="restaurants">Choose a restaurant:</label>
      <input list="restaurantList" id="restaurants" ngModel name="naam"/>
      <datalist id="restaurantList" name="naam">
        <option id="mcdonalds" name="naam" type="text">Mcdonalds</option>
        <option id="kentuckyfriedchicken" name="naam">Kentucky Fried Chicken</option>
        <option id="burgerking" name="naam">Burger King</option>
        <option id="dominospizza" name="naam">Domino's pizza</option>
      </datalist>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0"
          ngModel
          name="adres"
          required
          address>
      </div>

      <button type="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right"
              [disabled]="!f.valid" (click)="btnClick1();">Make
      </button>

    </form>
  </div>
```